# git 1 commit behind with fork, trying to solve this

Tags: git, github

I forked a repo on github, did some changes, submitted a PR and then problems started :)

The PR was accepted and part of the main code base. Then today I see that the PR is not part of the codebase anymore and it's pending. As if it got reverted,  not sure what happened.

Now, github shows me this:

> This branch is 8 commits ahead, 1 commit behind

and I want to catch up and not be 1 commit behind.

```
> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

so I did:

```
>  git pull upstream master
From github.com:...
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.

> git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 7 and 8 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

then I do:

```
> git pull
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.

> git push
Everything up-to-date
```

and I'm still 1 commit behind...

how to fix that?

---

Edit:

here is a screenshot of all the branches

[image]

---

Edit2:

output of:

git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all

[image]

Comment: thomas can go to your report and type in the command `gitk` and do a screenshot of all the branches/refs and commits so that everyone can see what is going on? and where things are diverging? If you do that, we can give you very specific commands to help you get where you want to go

Comment: @BKSpurgeon thanks for the help; I added a screenshot of all the branches

Comment: Your pull seems to be rebasing. Consider not rebasing as that’s modifying the history?

Comment: Thomas, you'll need to show something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6oU3.png, or post a graph showing the commit ids, otherwise it's very difficult to understand what and where you repo is right now.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon, I see what you mean now. Here it is: https://imgur.com/a/J5ZwbRn

Comment: Image not available.  Or just do `git graph` and prettify the results and paste that in

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I guess imgur doesn't keep these pics; here is a fresh one: https://imgur.com/a/boMUyhz

Comment: @Thomas try this git command which outputs the log in color format with all the commits on it as well - and post the results - someone will able to see what's going on and then guide you..`git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all`

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I ran the command, and updated the question with the output.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands -

1. *git pull--rebase origin master*
2. *git fetch origin*
3. *git merge origin <<< feature branch name >>>*
4. *git pull origin <<< feature branch name >>>*

Check for the status by executing- 'git status' command.
This will display that there are unmerged paths.
Run the '*git add -all*' command now re-run the commit and push commands to merge the local changes to master branch.

Comment: Why are you running two pulls and a fetch?

Comment: I just did all of this: https://imgur.com/a/fVwWHcP but no change

Answer (score 0):

ok  I think I have an idea of what's going on. But I could be wrong, so please review everything I've written very very carefully, especially the destructive actions in git.

please confirm that the following commits are in fact the same: de7be46 and 48bab83. Everything is predicated on these being essentially the same: `diff <(git show de7be46) <(git show 48bab83)`

`git checkout master`

`git checkout -b my-pr`

`git reset --hard 73fff1d`

`git cherry-pick 5b9f65f`

We want to cherry-pick because we want to retain this commit. I think that the `my-pr` branch will now contain all the commits relevant to your PR.

Now your my-pr branch and upstream/master should diverge from commit: 1c85914. I'm assuming that your PR work started from commit: 469ff29. (btw if that's the case I'd recommend making all PRs from a different branch (i.e. not master) to avoid confusion in the future.)

If you're satisfied that everything good then you can reset your master branch:

`git checkout master`

this moves the pointer so and will leave your existing commits dangling - so is "destructive":
`git reset --hard upstream/master`

this will be destructive:
`git push origin master --force`

Now your local master and upstream branches and origin/master will be in sync.

And your PR work will be located in branch: my-pr. And you can continue as before: make a new PR, or discard the work etc.

Comment: "git cherry-pick fb9f65f" returns "fatal: bad revision 'fb9f65f'"

Comment: that's the wrong commit id: try this instead: 5b9f65f  -- (btw are you understanding what we're trying to do here?)

Comment: actually no, I don't. I did try and it did destroy the PR which is not very important anyways since I have a backup; the pr doesn't exist in the new branch either. What I would be curious about is what happened in the first place? I don't understand the steps that led to that problem.

Comment: If you don't understand that's a big problem. Git tracks everything, so your PR exists somewhere in the repo - i made assumptions as to what / where your PR branch commits were. basically you probably want to get the commits associated with your PR in a separate branch, allowing you to your current master / origin branches to track what's upstream. Then when you are ready, merge your PR branch. An important part of using git is to understand how to recover: I would recommend taking the time to go through your commit history and reflog to understand what happened.

Comment: I looked at the history but couldn't find what the problem was here. I'm not very familiar with the PR feature though (2nd time I used it) but I still don't understand why this being 'behind' situation happened nor why I couldn't catch up.